# Postcode validation

Tags: javascript, html

I need to validate a part of my form which is the postcode based on Malaysia's postcode which is a 5 digit numeric postcode. How to validate a value enter by user which has exactly 5 numbers only no more and no less? Thanks in advance!

Here's my part of the code:

HTML:

```
<label>Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" required="required"></label><br />
```

Javascript:

```
function chkPostcode () {
    var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/; //check only alpha characters or space
    var postcodeOK = true;
    
    if ((postcode.length < 5 && postcode.length > 5)){ //same as owner==""
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Please enter postcode.\n"
        postcodeOK = false; //if condition or clause complex more readable if branches on separate lines
    }
    else{
        if (!pattern.test(postcode)){
        gErrorMsg = gErrorMsg + "Postcode must only contain numbers.\n"
        postcodeOK = false; //if condition or clause complex more readable if branches on separate lines
        }
    }
//if (!nameOk){
// document.getElementById("owner").style.borderColor = "red";
//
    return postcodeOK;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to ask a question!

Comment: What's the issue with this code?

Comment: whats wrong? however you only need `/^\d{5}$/`

Comment: `postcode.length < 5 && postcode.length > 5` will never be true. It cannot have more the 5 characters and less than 5 characters simultaneously. You need `||` instead of `&&`. As @AZ_ mentioned you can include the length check in regex itself.

Comment: @Evert sorry! i've edited my post and added in my question now

Comment: @adiga i want to validate whether the value entered is exactly 5 digits

Comment: @AZ_ ah i see thanks!

Comment: @adiga ah but isnt `||` is a or operator?

Comment: Yes, you need an OR operator. Think about it: `postcode.length < 5 && postcode.length > 5` What string has length greater than 5 AND length less than 5? You need to enter the `if` block if EITHER of them are true. Both of them can never be true at the same time.

Comment: ah i see thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You can either change it to `||` with your current code. Or, you can remove the length check and keep only regex check with `var pattern = /^\d{5}$/`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Your JavaScript is unnecessarily complicated. Here's a sure (and much better) way (except for all the ifs) to do this (the button and the check function are just for demo purposes):

```js
function chkPostcode() {
   var postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
   if(postcode.length !== 5)
   {
    return false;
   }
   else {
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(postcode.charAt(0)))) {
      if(!isNaN(parseInt(postcode.charAt(1)))) {
        if(!isNaN(parseInt(postcode.charAt(2)))) {
          if(!isNaN(parseInt(postcode.charAt(3)))) {
            if(!isNaN(parseInt(postcode.charAt(4)))) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
   return false;
}
function check() {
  if(chkPostcode()) alert("Valid!");
  else alert("Not a postcode");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="postcode" />
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Just keep in mind, although client side (JavaScript) validation scripts are helpful, it's easy to defeat client-side JavaScript. Make sure you make some validation on the server-side as well, where the client can't tamper with the code as easily.

Comment: ah i see thanks! the problem has been solved

Comment: This considers `"1abcd"` as valid postcode

Comment: so if i need the validator to validate the postcode which only can have numbers? ' ^[0-9]+$ ' this pattern can work right?

Comment: I just fixed it @adiga. Is there a better way to implement this though?

Comment: @cpwI fixed a bug that a commenter pointed out. Please use the new one.

Comment: Good god, please don't do that. What if there are 10 characters? You just need `if ( /^\d{5}$/.test(postcode) ) // valid postcode`

Answer (score 1):

This is a much shorter code for what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
document.getElementById("postcode").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  if ( /^\d{5}$/.test(e.target.value)){
    console.log("valid");
    return;
  }
  console.log("invalid");
})
```

```html
<label>Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" required="required"></label><br />
```